# Firebase PhoneAuth Is Not Working (While Another Auth Method Is Working) Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

On Firebase console, I made sure that the sign-in method has been enabled, SHA-1 for debugging and release, including the package name was correct. But, while another sign in method (e.g email, Google sign-in, anonymous) is working. Its always give me a FirebaseAuthException on phoneAuth method:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication, Please
>   verify that the correct package name and SHA-1.

I'm using a real device with an active sim card. have tried to add SMS & phone permission but still not working. Even when I'm using the testing phone number from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#integration-testing) (+1 650-555-3434)

Below is my code:

```
private void phoneVerification(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted : " + credential.getSmsCode());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onVerificationFailed : " +  e.toString());
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Quota exceeded.");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                           PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onCodeSent : " + verificationId);
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Edit**

After some trial error, I've found that the issue was not from SHA-1 or package. Its come from not whitelisting the number or using the same number from the documentation (+1 650-555-3434).

My questions are:

1. Can I use a real phone number during debugging or release without
   whitelisting it first on Firebase console?
2. Or this phone auth only allow the non-whitelisting number, if the
   app comes from the play store?